# Different borders when relative and asolute positioning is applied

Tags: html, css

Let we have a markup

```
<span>Text 
    <div>text</div> Text 
    <div>text</div> text 
</span>
```

and styles

```
span{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
div{margin:50px;}
```

It's OK. An inline-box generated by `span` element is splitting to three boxes. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6v5XG/). But if we change the positioning scheme of `span` to absolute we have that the border of span enclosed both `div` elements and a text inside the span. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6v5XG/1/).

Q: Why the positioning scheme is influenced to the border of span in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

Span is inline element so

Takes up only as much width as it needs, and does not force new lines

use this css

```
span{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    display: inline-block
}
```

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/6v5XG/3/

More info [reference](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Accept this as answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

A `span` is an inline element so has no positioning context associated with it to give it hasLayout. You would need to change your `span` to use `inline-block` in order to give it hasLayout. This article explains it quite well http://www.brunildo.org/test/ap_contbox1.html